# Android: Getting rgb values of image why bitmap giving error Null pointer exception

Tags: android, image, bitmap, rgb

I want to get rgb value of image.I'm getting image from gallery.And onclicklistener of image I'm trying to get rgb values but bitmap value is coming null.

getting image from gallery and setting to imageview.

```
Uri pickedImage = data.getData();       
String[] filePath = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(pickedImage, filePath, null, null, null);
cursor.moveToFirst();
String imagePath = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(filePath[0]));
imgView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath));
cursor.close();
```

getting rgb values code:

```
  int xCordinate =0;
  int yCordinate =0;
 bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)imgView.getBackground()).getBitmap();  //null pointer execption
 color = bitmap.getPixel(xCordinate, yCordinate);
 int r = Color.red(color); 
 int g = Color.green(color); 
 int b = Color.blue(color);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using `setImageBitmap()` to set a "foreground" bitmap in the image view but then retrieving the background with `getBackground()`. The background is `null` and calling `getBitmap()` on it will NPE.

Use `getDrawable()` in place of `getBackground()`.